# Face Detection using Haar - OpenCV python

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying this python code snippet:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
eye_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_eye.xml')

img = cv2.imread('img.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 3)
for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
    img = cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)
    roi_gray = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    roi_color = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    eyes = eye_cascade.detectMultiScale(roi_gray)
    for (ex,ey,ew,eh) in eyes:
        cv2.rectangle(roi_color,(ex,ey),(ex+ew,ey+eh),(0,255,0),2)

cv2.imshow('img',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

but I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 14, in <module>
    roi_color = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

I found this program [here](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_objdetect/py_face_detection/py_face_detection.html#face-detection).

Comment: Basically the error is because the `img` object is of type 'None' or in simple words it means that `img = cv2.imread('img.jpg')` is not able to locate the image path, this is probably because the current directory of the python program and the `img.jpg` are not same I will suggest you use the full path name , like : `img = cv2.imread(r'C:\\Documents\\images\\img.jpg')` , change the name of the directories as per your PC

Comment: I tried to put the path as you suggested, but the error occurs the same.

`img = cv2.imread ('/ home / deb / detection / 1 / img.jpg')`

Comment: try using : `img = cv2.imread (r'/home/deb/detection/1/img.jpg')`

Comment: Always the same mistake. I try to do some debugging to understand this better, it seems strange that it reads the image. Forgive my english is not very good.

Comment: So, finally the issue is fixed ?

Comment: No, always returns the same error.

Comment: ok let me run it on my machine.

Answer (score 3):

If you are sure that your image path is right and still the problem persist try doing this:

From this line

```
img = cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)
```

remove `img =`, let it be just

```
cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)
```

This worked for me.

Comment: please use [code formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and it appears that there is a bug in the code with the img variable.  It looks like there is confusion with the second setting of the img variable within the first 'for' loop.  Just make sure you also have the path to your image set correctly as well.

I changed the code to the following and it worked for me.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
eye_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_eye.xml')

img = cv2.imread('/path/to/your/image/img.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 3)
for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
    img2 = cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)
    roi_gray = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    roi_color = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    eyes = eye_cascade.detectMultiScale(roi_gray)
        for (ex,ey,ew,eh) in eyes:
            cv2.rectangle(roi_color,(ex,ey),(ex+ew,ey+eh),(0,255,0),2)

cv2.imshow('img',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: ^I had the same issue as the OP, and this works for me